Equality between rings of invariant differential operators
Let $G$ be a real connected Lie group in the Harish-Chandra class [GV - Definition 2.1.1]. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ denote its Lie algebra. This is a reductive Lie algebra and we have $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{z} \oplus \mathfrak{g}_s$, where $\mathfrak{z}$ is the center of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}_s = [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$. Let $G_s$ be the analytic subgroup of $G$ corresponding to $\mathfrak{g}_s$. This is a connected semi-simple Lie group with finite center. Let $K \subset G$ be a maximal compact subgroup and set $K_s = K \cap G_s$. Let $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{p}$ be the Cartan decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$ associated to  $\mathfrak{k}$, the Lie algebra of $K$. Similarly $\mathfrak{g}_s = \mathfrak{k}_s \oplus \mathfrak{p}_s$ is the Cartan decomposition associated to $\mathfrak{k}_s$, the Lie algebra of $K_s$. The symmetric space $G/K$ is isomorphic to the direct product of the Euclidean space $\mathfrak{z} \cap \mathfrak{p}$ with the symmetric space $G_s / K_s$ [GV - page 167].
Assume : $\mathfrak{z} \cap \mathfrak{p} = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ so that $S \overset{\text{def}}{=} G/K$ also equals $G_s / K_s$.
Let $\mathcal{D}$ (resp. $\mathcal{D}_s$) denote the $G$-invariants (resp. $G_s$-invariants) differential operators on $S$.
Question : Do we have $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}_s$ ?
Let $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{p}$ be a maximal abelian subspace and let $W(\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{g})$ denote the Weyl group of $(\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{g})$. Let $\mathfrak{a}_{\mathbb{C}} = \mathfrak{a} \otimes \mathbb{C}$ and $\text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{\mathbb{C}})$ be the associated symmetric algebra. Then, we have the Harish-Chandra isomorphism $\mathcal{D} \simeq \text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{\mathbb{C}})^{W(\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{g})}$, where $\text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{\mathbb{C}})^{W(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{g})}$ are the ${W(\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{g})}$-invariants of $\text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{\mathbb{C}})$ [GV - Theorem 2.6.7]. Similarly, we have $\mathcal{D}_s \simeq \text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{s, \mathbb{C}})^{W(\mathfrak{a}_s, \mathfrak{g}_s)}$ where $\mathfrak{a}_{s, \mathbb{C}} = \mathfrak{a}_{s} \otimes \mathbb{C}$ with $\mathfrak{a}_{s} \subset \mathfrak{p}_s$ a maximal abelian subspace and $W(\mathfrak{a}_s, \mathfrak{g}_s)$ the Weyl group of $(\mathfrak{a}_s, \mathfrak{g}_s)$.
Question bis : Do we have $\text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{\mathbb{C}})^{W(\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{g})} = \text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{s, \mathbb{C}})^{W(\mathfrak{a}_s, \mathfrak{g}_s)}$ ?
Proof ? Since $\mathfrak{z} \cap \mathfrak{p} = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, a maximal abelian subspace $\mathfrak{a}_s \subset \mathfrak{p}_s$ is a maximal abelian subspace $\mathfrak{a}_s \subset \mathfrak{p}$ and thus
\begin{equation*}
\text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{s, \mathbb{C}})^{W(\mathfrak{a}_s, \mathfrak{g})} \simeq \mathbb{C}[X_1, \ldots , X_r]\simeq \text{Sym}(\mathfrak{a}_{s, \mathbb{C}})^{W(\mathfrak{a}_s, \mathfrak{g}_s)}
\end{equation*}
where $r = \text{dim} (\mathfrak{a}_{s, \mathbb{C}})$, by Chevalley's theorem on invariants of finite reflexion groups ; see [Chevalley - Invariants of Finite Groups Generated by Reflections].
I am not very comfortable with these notions, but this proof seems correct to me while looking "too simple". Is it correct/where am I wrong ?
[GV] : R. Gangolli and V. S. Varadarajan - Harmonic Analysis of Spherical Functions on Real Reductive Groups.
